# Spherical Triangle — Angle from one Point without using North

Tags: spherical-coordinates, spherical-trigonometry

I'm designing a tool for students and right now im working with coordinates. I have the plan to shift the north pole in my code to Munich and I would like to do this by working with a spherical triangle and the angle at one point. As result I would like to have a formula which tells me how to calculate the angle at this specific point.

I tried couple of things, but the most examples use the normal north pole as a point. For my project I have three points: Munich, the antipod of Munich and for example let's say New York.

Munich is: N48° 08.107 E11° 34.918
The antipod is: S48° 08.107 W169° 24.082
New York: N40° 42.460 W74° 00.213

Now my problem is, I need to get the formula for the angle at Munich. I tried couple of things but I can't figure it out who to do this without using the north pole as a point.

Would be great if you guys give me a hint!

[Drawing of the Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOntM.png)